# Are the "key" and "value" terms for hash tables and associative arrays used interchangeably?

Tags: php, c, arrays, hashtable, associative

I've been following this intro to CS course.

When I was learning C, I learned about hash tables.

Hash tables are arrays that require a hash function to map a "key" to an integer value.
The value would be the index in the array.

"Key" -> [Hash function] -> value

array[value] = "Key"

Now, I'm learning about PHP, and I'm very confused about the use of associative arrays. In PHP we pass in a key (e.g. $_POST["key"] and it'll provide us with a value. So here the "key" is the index of the array, unlike the C hash table where they index was the value outputted by the hash function.

$_POST["key"] = Value

I've done a lot of searching and understand that hash tables and associative arrays are not 100% the same, but I'm very confused why these two different scenarios are using the terms "key" and "value" in different ways.

Am I seeing something wrong here?

Comment: Not the same language, not the same meaning. Like stage in english does not mean the same as stage in french. (theatre related in english, learning related in french).

Comment: A hash table is just one possible way to implement an associative array (they might also be implemented with trees, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"key" and "value" do not mean the same thing.

The *key* is the thing you feed into a hash table or PHP associative array or, generically, "map" to get back a *value*.

The confusion you're running into is that the *value* you get back from the hash table in your first example is then being used as a *key* (an array index) to a *different* thing (the array). Just as a person can be both a parent and a child, a number (or whatever) can be both a key (in one thing) and a value (in something else). It's a matter of what its role is in relation to the thing you're using it with.

Comment: As per this wikipedia image on the hash table page: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/58/Hash_table_4_1_1_0_0_1_0_LL.svg. Doesn't this imply that the hash value is the array's index and the key is what you store in that place of the array?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a "key" is some piece of data used to uniquely identify and retrieve some "value" from a data structure of some kind. But of course the word "value" can mean many other things as well.

For example, if your language has built-in hash tables like Python or JavaScript, you can just say `table[key] = value` to store something and `value = table[key]` to retrieve it. If you're making your own hash tables, you might first have to compute a hash function of the key, and then compute an array index from the hash, and then put the value in the array at that index. A writer might refer to the result of a hash function as a "hash value", and he might refer to an array index as an array "key", so yes, it can get confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I am inclined to say that the word "key" is used wrong in the first exampe/statement of your CS course:

> Hash tables are arrays that require a hash function to map a "key" to an integer value. The value would be the index in the array.

The statement could better be:

> Hash tables are arrays that require a hash function to map an input value of some kind to an integer value, called the *hash value*. The hash value would be the index in the array.
>
> input value -> [Hash function] -> hash value

Further, the statement:

> array[value] = "Key"

is wrong because the hash function can genereate the same hash value for multiple input values. In general, `array[value]` will yield a *list* of all input values for which the hash function calculates the same hash value.

An *associative array* is an array notation to tell the machine to retrieve the information associated with a unique key (the array index) from a data set (the array name). Underneath the machine will execute an algorithm to search/retrieve this information. A programming language can provide the programmer with associative arrays (notation) to help the programmer write his program. So it is just an array *notation*, it is not array *indexing*, as in the hash array in C.